# Finding the source of a circular dependency error in Dagger (building with Bazel)

Tags: android, dagger-2, bazel

I'm working on converting an Android app that currently builds Gradle to be built with Bazel. We have many modules/targets and we use Dagger for DI. Of course, the codebase builds just fine with Gradle but when switching to Bazel we get the following error:

```
error: [ComponentProcessor:MiscError] dagger.internal.codegen.ComponentProcessor was unable to process this interface because not all of its dependencies could be resolved. Check for compilation errors or a circular dependency with generated code
```

There is no other error message or compilation error printed out.

I tried using `--verbose_failures` to get more information, but didn't get any. I tried disabling hjar generation with `--nojava_header_compilation` but that didn't help either.

All our annotation-processors have `generates_api=1` (I also tried without, just because I ran out of ideas).

Unfortunately, I can not share code snippets and I don't have a reproducing example.
What I'm looking for are tips for how to find this circular dependency and how to get more information about the error from Dagger.